# MariaDB 11.0 to 11.1 GA fails with ERROR 1210 (HY000) at line 32: Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY

Tags: mariadb, update, upgrade, windows-server

I upgraded to MariaDB 11 some time ago, and all has been working well for a long time. I saw there was a newer GA release, 11.1, so decided to update to that, but the upgrade fails. This is on Windows server. Checking the upgrade log, it stalls here

```
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.transaction_registry                         OK
Phase 2/8: Installing used storage engines... Skipped
Phase 3/8: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
ERROR 1210 (HY000) at line 29: Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY
ERROR 1210 (HY000) at line 32: Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY
ERROR 1210 (HY000) at line 251: Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY
ERROR 1210 (HY000) at line 299: Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY
ERROR 1210 (HY000) at line 303: Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY
```

I see this error in a few places, but mostly regarding 5.x version that are very old. My 11 was and is working fine!  I have my datadir in a completely independent folder on another drive D:\MariaDB\Data. DataDir is set to this. It has always been OK. I don't see the issue. Can anyone suggest a workaround?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I seem to have resolved this (after a few hours!). Changing to InnoDB per file, and doing a full repair/optimise and recreate using the old version (11) of MariaDB, then manually running mysql_service_upgrade, and it completed!